# Disable automatic client failover

Tags: sql-server, sqlclient

We have to instances of SQL Server mirrored.

If you connect to the primary, and then try to connect again and it fails, the next time you try and connect it will try and connect to the slave.

From what I understand, SQL Server will send down the mirroring partner when you first connect and cache it.

We have a manual process in place to failover if we need to, and don't want this behavior. Mostly because it fails due to the failover not being automatic on the server side.

How can I specify (preferably server side) that I don't want the SQL Client to try to connect to the slave if there's a failure?

Comment: Oddly a search for [sql server disable failover](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+disable+failover&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS727US727&oq=sql+server+disable+failover&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l2.4624j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) finds answers like [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e8c0693d-403b-4576-81cb-4845de8ad24f/disable-automated-failover-of-sql-server-instance-to-other-node-in-the-cluster?forum=winserverClustering)

Comment: Hmm. I've read through most of that. Thanks for the link, though it doesn't solve my problem.